# Не отображается recyclerview после подгрузки БД

Tags: java, android

Не отображается recyclerview  после подгрузки БД. Перед тем как подключать БД проверял recyclerview все корректно отображалось. Ошибок код не выдает.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<ListItem> listItems;
private static final String URL_DATA = 
"https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/marvel/";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclirView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    loadRecyclerViewDeata();


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) 
    findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

private void loadRecyclerViewDeata() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading.....");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(s);

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            ListItem item = new ListItem(
                                    o.getString("name"),
                                    o.getString("realname")
                            );
                            listItems.add(item);
                        }
                        adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, 
     getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_ABFilt) {
        return true;
    } else if (id== R.id.action_Pawns){
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_OOP) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Procedyre) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_WEB) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Что-то я здесь в упор не вижу работы с БД и не представляю как она может помешать правильной работе этого класса.

Comment: @woesss подозреваю, что имелась ввиду удаленная БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не использовал `Volley`, поэтому возможно обновить UI вам надо будет обратившись к основному потоку, но похоже, что у вас ошибка парсинга, о чем упомянул @A.Shakhov.

Вместо

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(s);
```

Попробуйте

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);
```

Помимо этого убедитесь, что Вы добавили в манифесте разрешение на использование интернета:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Еще хотелось бы добавить, что Вы можете использовать библиотеку [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) которая упростит работу с парсингом `json`a.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вы для RecyclerView устанавливаете адаптер не в UI потоке (думаю, что onResponse выполняется в отдельном потоке)
Попробуйте так:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
      recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);                
   }
});
```